# How to get decimal value of a unicode character in c++

Tags: c++, unicode, qt4

For one of my opensource projects, i need to compute the decimal equivalent of a given unicode character.

For example if tamil character `L'அ'` is given, the output should be 2949 .

I am using c++ in Qt environment. I googled and could not find a solution for this. Please help if you know a solution for this.

Comment: What you're looking for is called the Unicode codepoint of a character.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [unicode()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/qchar.html#unicode-2) method of the `QChar` object (which you can get e.g. with the `at` method of a `QString`, if a `QString` is what you have to start with).

Comment: Thanks a lot. unicode() method of QChar gave the required result.

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << (int)c
```

that's it

Comment: I also tried this before posting. But it dont worked for unicode characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
void print_decimal(wchar_t character)
{
  std::cout << int(character);
}
```