# How do i get the decimal value of a unicode character in C#?

Tags: c#, string, unicode, localization

How do i get the numeric value of a unicode character in C#?

For example if tamil character `அ` ([U+0B85](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b85/index.htm)) given, output should be `2949` (i.e. `0x0B85`)

### See also

- C++: [How to get decimal value of a unicode character in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714154/how-to-get-decimal-value-of-a-unicode-character-in-c)
- Java: [How can I get a Unicode character's code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006533/how-can-i-get-a-unicode-characters-code)

### Multi code-point characters

Some characters require multiple code points. In this example, UTF-16, each code unit is still in the Basic Multilingual Plane:

- [image] (i.e. `U+0072` `U+0327` `U+030C`)
- [image] (i.e. `U+0072` `U+0338` `U+0327` `U+0316` `U+0317` `U+0300` `U+0301` `U+0302` `U+0308` `U+0360`)

The larger point being that one "character" can require more than 1 UTF-16 code unit, it can require more than 2 UTF-16 code units, it can require more than 3 UTF-16 code units.

The larger point being that one "character" can require dozens of unicode code points. In UTF-16 in C# that means more than 1 `char`. One *character* can require 17 `char`.

My question was about converting `char` into a UTF-16 encoding value. Even if an entire string of 17 `char` only represents one "character", i still want to know how to convert each UTF-16 unit into a numeric value.

e.g.

```
String s = "அ";

int i = Unicode(s[0]);
```

[Where `Unicode` returns the integer value, as defined by the Unicode standard, for the first character of the input expression.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180059.aspx)

Comment: What is your input? A string containing a single character?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `char` (or `MyString[3]`, which is a char)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Basically i was looking for the C# equivalent of the SQL Server `Unicode` function (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180059.aspx)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's basically the same as Java. If you've got it as a `char`, you can just convert to `int` implicitly:

```
char c = '\u0b85';

// Implicit conversion: char is basically a 16-bit unsigned integer
int x = c;
Console.WriteLine(x); // Prints 2949
```

If you've got it as part of a string, just get that single character first:

```
string text = GetText();
int x = text[2]; // Or whatever...
```

Note that characters not in the basic multilingual plane will be represented as two UTF-16 code units. There *is* support in .NET for finding the full Unicode code point, but it's not *simple*.

Comment: Even characters in the BMP, like `Ä` (`A` + `¨`) are represented as two UTF-16 code units. But the point is taken: hard-cast a `char` to numeric

Comment: @IanBoyd: Well various characters *can* be represented using composition, but can also be represented as single UTF-16 code units. By definition if it's in the BMP it has a code point less than 64K, so  can be represented as a UTF-16 code unit :)

Comment: @Jon: Do you have any pointer regarding surrogate pairs identification? TIA.

Comment: @Serge-appTranslator: Have a look at `char.ConvertToUtf32(string, int)`, `char.IsLowSurrogate` etc.

Comment: Oops! Sorry: Google, in addition to being your employer, is my friend: Char.IsHighSurrogate(ch), Char.IsLowSurrogate(ch), Char.IsSurrogatePair()

Comment: Wanting to add on a comment for anyone coming by later, in .NET (starting with Core 3, and now in 5, 6, etc.) there is a Rune class that can help with getting the full Unicode code point and representing that in situations where there's surrogate char pairs. So in situations where you're trying to get the full code point for a single display character (like an emoji or a character not on the basic plane), Rune can be of some help. But it's not a full replacement for char.

Answer (score 9):

```
((int)'அ').ToString()
```

If you have the character as a `char`, you can cast that to an `int`, which will represent the character's numeric value. You can then print that out in any way you like, just like with any other integer.

If you wanted hexadecimal output instead, you can use:

```
((int)'அ').ToString("X4")
```

`X` is for hexadecimal, `4` is for zero-padding to four characters.

Answer (score 5):

> How do i get the numeric value of a unicode character in C#?

A `char` is not necessarily the whole Unicode [code point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point). In UTF-16 encoded languages such as C#, you may actually need 2 `char`s to represent a single "logical" character. And your string lengths migh not be what you expect - the [MSDN documnetation for String.Length Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length.aspx) says:

*"The Length property returns the number of Char objects in this instance, not the number of Unicode characters."*

- So, if your Unicode character is encoded in just one `char`, it is already numeric (essentially an unsigned 16-bit integer). You may want to *cast* it to some of the integer types, but this won't change the actual bits that were originally present in the `char`.
- If your Unicode character is 2 `char`s, you'll need to multiply one by 2^16 and add it to the other, resulting in a `uint` numeric value:

  char c1 = ...;
  char c2 = ...;
  uint c = ((uint)c1 << 16) | c2;

> How do i get the decimal value of a unicode character in C#?

When you say "decimal", this usually means a character string containing only characters that a human being would interpret as decimal digits.

- If you can represent your Unicode character by only one `char`, you can convert it to decimal string simply by:

  char c = 'அ';
  string s = ((ushort)c).ToString();
- If you have 2 `chars` for your Unicode character, convert them to a `uint` as described above, then call `uint.ToString`.

**--- EDIT ---**

AFAIK diacritical marks are considered separate "characters" (and separate code points) despite being visually rendered together with the "base" character. Each of these code points taken alone is still at most 2 UTF-16 code units.

BTW I think the proper name for what you are talking about is not "character" but ["combining character"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character). So yes, a single **combining** character can have more than 1 code point and therefore more than 2 code units. If you want a decimal representation of such as combining character, you can probably do it most easily through `BigInteger`:

```
string c = "\x0072\x0338\x0327\x0316\x0317\x0300\x0301\x0302\x0308\x0360";
string s = (new BigInteger(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(c))).ToString();
```

Depending on what order of significance of the code unit "digits" you wish, you may want reverse the `c`.

Comment: A character is not limited to 2 code points. For example, the character `A̖͇͉͉͉᷿̿᷾︡︠ͯ҄͟͟` is made up of 13 code points (The latin capital letter `A` along with a bunch of diacritic marks). (display support depends on browser). But what i want, and what i can get, still mesh with `(int)MyString[i]`, each code point has a decimal value that corresponds to a `U+xxxx`.

Comment: @IanBoyd I think you are confusing code "point" with code "unit". Code **point** represents a "logical" character (the current Unicode has 1,114,112 of them) and is not specific to any particular encoding. On the other hand, a code **unit** is specific to encoding. AFAIK, a code unit in UTF-16 can appear either alone or in a surrogate pair, certainly not in an array of 13 code units.  Are you talking about some encoding other than UTF-16?

Comment: i was talking about a character made up of more than two code points (which in UTF-16 more than two code units). e.g. small latin `r` with `caron` and `cedilla` (`U+0072 U+0327 U+030C`) is a single character. You can have even more complicated characters, made up of 13 UTF-16 code units. Updated question with picture of such a character.

Comment: @IanBoyd Please see the --- EDIT --- in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
char c = 'அ';
short code = (short)c;
ushort code2 = (ushort)c;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of using Plane 1, the Supplementary Multilingual Plane (SMP):

```
string single_character = "\U00013000"; //first Egyptian ancient hieroglyph in hex
//it is encoded as 4 bytes (instead of 2)

//get the Unicode index using UTF32 (4 bytes fixed encoding)
Encoding enc = new UTF32Encoding(false, true, true);
byte[] b = enc.GetBytes(single_character);
Int32 code = BitConverter.ToInt32(b, 0); //in decimal
```