# Convert Unicode string made up of culture-specific digits to integer value

Tags: c#, .net, numbers, globalization, culture

I am developing a program in the Marathi language. In it, I want to add/validate numbers entered in Marathi Unicode by getting their actual integer value.

For example, in Marathi:

- ४५ = 45
- ९९ = 99

How do I convert this Marathi string `"४५"` to its actual integer value i.e. `45`?

I googled a lot, but found nothing useful. I tried using `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString()` to get string and then tried to parse, but failed here also.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826162/how-do-i-get-the-decimal-value-of-a-unicode-character-in-c.

Comment: Is there a logic where you can map characters to integers and then calculate from there? Something like [parsing roman numbers](http://vadivel.blogspot.de/2011/09/how-to-convert-roman-numerals-to.html)

Comment: FYI, `int.Parse()` isn't likely to work in this case, since the documentation for [`NumberFormatInfo.NativeDigits`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.nativedigits.aspx) says: _"The character set that is specified by the `NativeDigits` property has no effect on parsing or formatting operations. Only the Basic Latin digits `0` (U+0030) through `9` (U+0039) are used when formatting or parsing numeric values or date and time values."_

Comment: @Guruprasad - You should accept the answer rather than putting {Solved} in the title.

Answer (score 4):

Correct way would be to use [Char.GetNumericValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7k33ktz.aspx) that lets you to convert individual characters to corresponding numeric values and than construct complete value. I.e. `Char.GetNumericValue('९')` gives you 9.

Depending on your goal it may be easier to replace each national digit character with corresponding invariant digit and use regular parsing functions.

```
Int32.Parse("९९".Replace("९", "9"))
```

Comment: This is the right answer but it's disappointing you need to go so low-level, what with textual support being so good.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov Thanks for the solution but the code fails when value is in decimal format (like १२३.३२१ = latin Equ. 123.321)..

Answer (score 2):

Quick hack of @Alexi's response.

```
public static double ParseValue(string value)
{
    return double.Parse(string.Join("",
        value.Select(c => "+-.".Contains(c)
           ? "" + c: "" + char.GetNumericValue(c)).ToArray()),
        NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
}
```

calling ParseValue("१२३.३२१") yields 123.321 as result

Comment: What about negative numbers, e.g. `"-१२३.३२१"`? ;)

Comment: Thanks @Roger but while using your code it is giving me following errors

1. The best overloaded method match for 'string.Join(string, string[])' has some invalid arguments

2. cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]'


Please Help ....Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, fixed the problem (only exists in pre .NET 4.0) so it should work correctly now

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution... 
The following code will convert given Marathi number to its equivalent Latin number..
Thanks to @Alexei, I just changed some of your code and its working fine..

```
 string ToLatinDigits(string nativeDigits)
    {
        int n = nativeDigits.Length;
        StringBuilder latinDigits = new StringBuilder(capacity: n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            if (char.IsDigit(nativeDigits, i))
            {
                latinDigits.Append(char.GetNumericValue(nativeDigits, i));
            }
            else if (nativeDigits[i].Equals('.') || nativeDigits[i].Equals('+') || nativeDigits[i].Equals('-'))
            {
                latinDigits.Append(nativeDigits[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Invalid Argument");
            }
        }
        return latinDigits.ToString();
    }
```

This method is working for both + and - numbers.
Regards Guruprasad

Answer (score 0):

[Windows.Globalization.DecimalFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.globalization.numberformatting.decimalformatter.parseint.aspx) will parse different [numeral systems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj236471.aspx) in addition to Latin, including Devanagari (which is what is used by Marathi).